# WCF Dispatcher 'Sub' instrumentation

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, wcf-binding, interceptor

I have few WCF operations (all one-way messsages)

```
Public Sub WCFOperation()
    DoSomeWork()
    AgainDoSomeWork()
End Sub
```

I would like to know how much of time has been spent from starting of the WCFOperation to end of the Sub. Say, for DoSomeWork if it takes 100 msec and for AgainDoSomeWork takes 212 msec. The total should be 212 msec.

I would like the above operation to be performed in WCF channel stack. Currently I am looking at this link [WCF Dispatcher](http://www.edmundyeung.com/Code/extending-wcf-services-with-dispatcher-extensions)

Any help will be really appreciated.

**Addendum:** Rephrasing the question. I would like a method in WCF internal class (IOperationInvoker or any other interceptor class's method) to be invoked once the code point reaches 'End Sub'

Comment: are you going to send it back in response?

Comment: I won't send it back in response. I would prefer to log the amount of time spent on methods in a Database. So, a user who creates a new method WCFOperationNew never needs to know about the internals.

Comment: then just start a watch before starting the works, stop it once done, then log it.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I can have timer on any OperationInvoker or other sort of classes. Will I be intimated when the WCFOperation has completed it's job? I mean how do I know that I reached 'End Sub' statement in the Sub?